# Performance (JAVA) ~ String concatenation in a loop with prepending and appending

Tags: java, string, performance, loops, concatenation

I'm having performance issues. Does anyone have a faster/better solution for doing the following:

```
    String main = "";
    for (String proposition : propositions) {
        if (main.length() == 0) {
            main = proposition;
        } else {
            main = "|(" + proposition + "," + main + ")";
        }
    }
```

I know concat and stringbuilder are faster, but i don't see how i can use these methods. Because of the following line of code:

```
main = "|(" + proposition + "," + main + ")";
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to achieve? what's your expected result?

Comment: @AndrewTobilko He wants a faster way to do this for performance.

Comment: Have you tried inserting into a StringBuilder? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert(int,%20java.lang.String) Or reverse the `propositions` before iterating, would that allow you to append only?

Comment: In general, when working with strings, it is much better to use a `StringBuilder`, and after getting your desired string use the method `toString()`

Comment: Can `proposition.length()` be zero? Looping backwards might make it easier to use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf: The upvoters might have upvoted because converting this code to use more efficient forms of string building isn't actually trivial, due to the mixed prepending and appending.

Comment: Related to, but not a duplicate of, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So from what I can tell there are 3 problems here:

1. Values are primarily prepended to the string.
2. For each value a character is appended.
3. If only one value is present, nothing should be appended or prepended.
4. With 2 or more items, the 0th item is handled differently:

> 0:""
>
> 1:"A"
>
> 2:"|(B,A)"
>
> 3:"|(C,|(B,A))"

It can be made quicker by making a few changes:

1. Reverse the algorithm, this means the majority of the work involves appending, allowing you to use StringBuilders.
2. Count the number of closing `)`'s and append those after the loop is finished.
3. Special case for 0 or 1 items in the list.

With those changes the algorithm should be able to use a StringBuilder and be a lot quicker.

Attempt at an algorithm:

```
int length = propositions.size();
if (length == 0) {
    main = "";
} else {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int nestingDepth = 0;
    // Reverse loop, ignoring 0th element due to special case
    for (int i = length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        sb.append("|(").append(propositions.get(i)).append(',');
        nestingDepth++;
    }
    // Append last element due to special casing
    sb.append(propositions.get(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < nestingDepth; i++) {
        sb.append(')');
    }

    main = sb.toString();
}
```

I *believe* this should produce the correct results, but it should give the right idea.

Comment: He doesn't need to reverse the algorithm. `StringBuilder.insert()` exists.

Comment: @EJP: But using `insert` defeats the point, because you wouldn't have done anything about the quadratic runtime.

Comment: @EJP insert would require moving all the previous input, it would probably involve as much shuffling of memory as the original code.

Comment: insert may need to move input, but would still be faster than the original which creates all these strings

Comment: @Robert However both moving memory (insert) and allocating memory (naive) are situations you want to avoid within a loop. Hence why I suggested a reverse iteration because that turns it into a problem the stringbuilder is designed for.

Comment: Another option is to use an `ArrayDeque`, which is a circular structure that inserts at the start just as fast as the end. At the end you could join all the strings.

Comment: I'm going to try this method, thanks for responding all.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you're prepending and appending to the string as you go. String and StringBuilder dont handle this well (and give quadratic performance). But you can use a dequeue  which supports insertion at start and end to store all the pieces. Then finally you can join the bits in the dequeue.

```
ArrayDeque bits = new ArrayDeque();
for (String proposition : propositions) {
    if (bits.size() == 0) {
        bits.push(proposition);
    } else {
        // Add prefix
        main.offerFirst("|(" + proposition + "," );
        // Add suffix
        main.push(")");
    }
}
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for( String s : bits) {
   sb.append(s);
}
main = sb.toString();
```

Comment: I'm going to try this method, thanks for responding all.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is an array of `propositions`, you could first sum the length of the `String`(s) in the array. Add 4 for your additional characters, and subtract 4 because you don't use those separators on the first element. That should be the *perfect* size for your output (this is optional, because `StringBuilder` is dynamically sized). Next, construct a `StringBuilder`. Add the first element. All subsequent elements follow the same pattern, so the loop is simplified with a traditional `for`. Something like,

```
int len = Stream.of(propositions).mapToInt(s -> s.length() + 4).sum() - 4;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len); // <-- len is optional
sb.append(propositions[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < propositions.length; i++) {
    sb.insert(0, ",").insert(0, propositions[i]).insert(0, "|(").append(")");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

Comment: I'm going to try this method, thanks for responding all.